# How to get lemmas from sentences in DKPro/UIMA?

Tags: java, nlp, uima, dkpro-core

I'm trying to setup a pipeline, which produces lemmatized sentences. I know how to get either all sentences or all lemmas, but I don't know how to get collections of lemmas divided by sentence ends. Here is a code snippet with a missing argument marked by `??????`:

```
AnalysisEngine pipeline = createEngine(createEngineDescription( 
                              createEngineDescription(BreakIteratorSegmenter.class),
                              createEngineDescription(StanfordLemmatizer.class),
                              createEngineDescription(StopWordRemover.class, StopWordRemover.PARAM_MODEL_LOCATION,
                                  new String[]{"stopwords.txt"})));

JCas jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();

jcas.setDocumentText    ("Almost all energy on Earth comes from the Sun. Plants make food energy from sunlight.");
jcas.setDocumentLanguage("en");
pipeline.process        (jcas);

for (Sentence s : select(jcas, Sentence.class)) {
  out.println("");

  for (Lemma l : select(??????, Lemma.class)) 
    out.print(l.getValue() + " ");
}
```

What do I need to change in this code, so it prints lemmas from two input sentences in two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for (Lemma l : JCasUtil.selectCovered(Lemma.class, s)) 
    out.print(l.getValue() + " ");
```

*Disclosure: I am working on the Apache UIMA project*

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `The method selectCovered(Class<T>, AnnotationFS) in the type JCasUtil is not applicable for the arguments (Sentence, Class<Lemma>)` error.

Comment: Sorry, got the order wrong - updated. First the class, then the covering annotation.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. BTW, what is the best place to find this kind of detailed specification?

Comment: Well, it's in the Java API documentation: http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/api/index.html?org/apache/uima/fit/util/JCasUtil.html

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but where is the documentation of `JCas` class? There are only `JCas*` classes there. Specifically, I want to replace `jcas.setDocumentText` with reading from .txt or .epub file.

Comment: Documentation JCas is in the UIMA Core SDK documentation - all the UIMA Core documentation is linked here: https://uima.apache.org/documentation.html

Comment: For reading from a file, you'd need to use a Collection Reader. DKPro Core has a TextReader (https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.7.0/apidocs/index.html?de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/io/text/TextReader.html) - I am currently not aware of an epub reader. - See also: https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/documentation/